# ORA-01427 single-row subquery returns more that one row

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, ora-01427

I have run into a problem with Oracle SQL the Error is: 
**ORA-01427 single-row subquery returns more that one row**
I am trying to find the locations that have at least one vehicle with manual
transmission that has lower mileage than any luxury vehicle at that location.

**Here is My Table**

```
VID          MILEAGE         LOCATION        VSIZE        TRANSMISSION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
V-101       70               AHMD            COMPACT      AUTOMATIC
V-102       50               SURAT           COMPACT      AUTOMATIC
V-103       10               AHMD            MID-SIZE     MANUAL
V-104       30               AHMD            MID-SIZE     AUTOMATIC
V-105       15               VADODARA        FULL-SIZE    AUTOMATIC
V-106       20               AHMD            LUXURY       AUTOMATIC
V-107       50               AHMD            LUXURY       MANUAL
```

**And this is my Query:**

```
SELECT location, transmission, mileage FROM vehicles_workshop 
  WHERE transmission = 'MANUAL' AND mileage = 
      ( SELECT DISTINCT mileage FROM vehicles_workshop WHERE mileage < 
          (SELECT MAX(mileage) FROM vehicles_workshop WHERE vsize = 'LUXURY')
      );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of equal to operator use `IN` before subquery

```
SELECT location, transmission, mileage FROM vehicles_workshop 
  WHERE transmission = 'MANUAL' AND mileage IN
      ( SELECT DISTINCT mileage FROM vehicles_workshop WHERE mileage < 
          (SELECT MAX(mileage) FROM vehicles_workshop WHERE vsize = 'LUXURY')
      );
```

Your subquery for comparing mileage is returning more than one value but equal to operator can work to compare only single values and so error is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT location, transmission, mileage 
FROM vehicles_workshop t1
WHERE transmission = 'MANUAL'         --manual transmission
  AND EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM vehicles_workshop t2 
        WHERE vsize = 'LUXURY'        --luxury vehicle
        AND t2.location = t1.location --same location
        AND t2.mileage  > t1.mileage) --higher mileage
      ;
```